# looking for regular expression way to get sub string before 2nd dot

Tags: c#

I have below kind of string in below format,

```
string str = "8.8.0.4566";
```

First I need to validate the format using regular expression "(\d*.\d*).+/)" and then need to extract sub-string before 2nd dot.

I am able to that using below, but looking for regular expression way to validate and extract,

```
 str= str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('.', str.IndexOf('.') + 1));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s = "8.8.0.4566";

var pattern = @"(?'first_two'\d+\.\d+)(\.\d+){2}";

var match = new Regex(pattern).Match(s);

Console.WriteLine(match.Value); //prints '8.8.0.4566'
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["first_two"].Value); //prints '8.8'
```

Answer (score 2):

[Try this link here](https://regex101.com/r/6ZX3tG/1)

```
^[^.]*\.[^.]*
```

Answer (score 2):

You can validate it and get the substring with this regex:

```
^(\d+\.\d+)(\.\d+)+
```

The needed substring is in group 1. Check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/YUvKAC/3)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to "extract" everything before 2nd dot ( `.` ) then why not use a positive lookahead :

```
string str = "8.8.0.4566";
string pattern = @"^\d+.\d+(?=\.)";
var match = new Regex(pattern).Match(str);
// do something with match
```

Or simply :

```
string str = "8.8.0.4566";
string pattern = @"^(\d+\.){2}";
var match = new Regex(pattern).Match(str);
string result = match.Value.Substring(0, match.Length - 1);
```

---

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JvJGOx/1)
[Rextester](http://rextester.com/LSD13421)